# Relation between ideals in Noetherian domains.

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Suppose that we have a Noetherian domain $R$ and two ideals $I$ and $J$ of $R.$
Now consider the minimal (or irredundant) primary decompositions $I=\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^r Q_i$ and $J=\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^s Q'_i$ of $I$ and $J$ respectively. If $I\supseteq J,$ are there any relations between the ideals appearing in the decompositions of $I$ and $J$ and the numbers $s$ and $r$?

For example if $R$ is a Dedekind domain, when we write an ideal as a product of prime ideals, we are able to obtain relations  between the exponents of the prime ideals appearing in the decomposition of $I$ and $J.$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A short answer is no. For instance, consider a local ring with maximal ideal $m$. Then the primary decomposition for $m$ is itself, whereas the primary decompositions for ideals might be arbitrary. Dedekind domains are special since it forces the heights of ideals the same provided that they are not zero ideals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Youngsu mentioned above, there is in general no relation between the primary components of $I$ and $J$, or the numbers $r$ and $s$ (and Youngsu has given the example of $I = m$ in a local ring for a case where $r < s$).

For an example with $r > s$: take $R = k[x,y]$, $I = (x) \cap (x,y)^2 = (x^2,xy) \supseteq J = (x^2)$.

On a positive note, there are relations among the radicals of the primary components, i.e. the associated primes of $I$ and $J$. If $I = \bigcap_{i=1}^r Q_i \supseteq J = \bigcap_{i=1}^s Q_i'$, then writing $P_i = \sqrt{Q_i}$, $P_i' = \sqrt{Q_i'}$ yields

$$\bigcap_{i=1}^r P_i = \sqrt{I} \supseteq \sqrt{J} = \bigcap_{i=1}^s P_i'$$

Thus for every $i = 1, \ldots, r$, there exists $j$ such that $P_i \supseteq P_j'$ (in fact we can always choose $P_j' \in \text{Min}(J)$). More information can also be obtained from the short exact sequence $0 \to I/J \to R/J \to R/I \to 0$, which implies e.g. that every associated prime of $J$, that is not associated to $I/J$, is in fact an associated prime of $I$.